# Are there any Christian denominations that believe in sex and marriage in the afterlife?

Tags: marriage, heaven, denomination-survey, afterlife, sex-acts

After an interesting set of articles put forward in  the chatroom,  I'm curious to know if any christian denominations have said a marriage can continue in heaven, and if the conjugal act continues in heaven.

PS. I find the topic interesting but I am one of the Christians that believe marriage and sexual feelings vanish after death.

Comment: Is your question directed at whether or not the glorified body (which some denominations believe in) will be able to engage in sex, or is that not where you are headed with this question?

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Any beliefs of a bond of Marriage or sexual emotions beyond death within a Christian circle.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but as written might be too broad since a number of denominations have different beliefs in the afterlife.  You may want to narrow the scope a bit.  (And for some reason I think we have a related question to this, I just have not found it yet).

Comment: I'm the one who sparked that conversation by linking to this article on my blog: [Is There Sex in Heaven?](https://leewoof.org/2018/02/27/is-there-sex-in-heaven/) That article answers the question in its title with a "yes." And since I represent a Christian denomination (Swedenborgian), clearly there is at least one Christian denomination that says that marriage and the conjugal act continue in the afterlife, which means you should already know that the answer to your question is "yes." So I'm a little confused as to why you are asking the question.

Comment: @Lee Woofenden I did not know that belief was held by all the Swedenborgians, I assumed the blog represented your personal thoughts on the topic.

Comment: Yes, all Swedenborgians believe that marriage, and sex, continue after death. Swedenborg was very clear on that. And popular belief to the contrary notwithstanding, Jesus actually *didn't* say that there's no marriage in the resurrection. Our belief is that the Bible overwhelmingly supports eternal marriage based especially on our being created male and female by God from the beginning to be united in marriage, and that what God does is eternal, not temporary.

Comment: If your question doesn't get closed, I would be happy to provide an answer along these lines.

Comment: About the blog, though there is, of course, some element of personal opinion, which I usually label as such, most of what's there represents the general thinking of the more liberal end of the Swedenborgian spectrum. The specifically doctrinal posts on traditional theological topics such as God, the Scriptures, atonement, salvation, and so on are largely straight Swedenborgian doctrine, embraced by all Swedenborgians. I am, after all, an ordained Swedenborgian minister.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The LDS Church teaches that while not all marriages are eternal (see Luke 20:34-35), but that a marriage which is sealed is, and will continue in heaven. Additionally parents that are sealed to their children will still play a parental role in the afterlife.

As for what marriage will be like in the next life, we do not know, but some sources suggest that those in the celestial kingdom will be able to keep having children forever (if this process is the same or different is similarly up to speculation).

Answer (score -1):

Don't think so. However, if you are among those who believe in the resurrection hope, being brought back to life in similar fashion such as Lazarus or Jairus' daughter, people will continue to resume God's original plan, that is, to populate the earth, as seen mentioned in The Book of Genesis.

Comment: Well the answer above you gives one denomination that does. The rest looks like your personal opinion, not that of any denomination.

Comment: If it's not your personal opinion, then please [edit] this to explain which denomination(s)' views it does represent.

Comment: On the contrary, I am not going on personal opinion however, rather, I am stating what God's purpose was for mankind from the start. This is in connection with what Adam and Eve had lose, of which mankind itself will gain. Granted those with the hope of resurrection will benefit from God's intent. That said, there is no other group that holds the belief regarding the question itself. I am aware of the LDS, however, that was already mentioned, therefore, I do not think there is any other group that holds this view, hence my response. Also still new to this comment thing, so I'll edit later.

Comment: So I have done some digging and came to the same conclusion. If there is any denomination that believes in the same thing (Celestial marriage) and or similar, nothing. Just the one that was already mention.

Comment: And how many gazillion _earths_ will God need to create to house all of the people who continued procreating throughout all eternity?  Remember, eternity never ends.  Don't you suppose there is a reason that Jesus taught there would be no marriage in Heaven?