# Which denominations believe in eternal marriage?

Tags: marriage, denomination-survey, afterlife

Which Christian denominations believe that marriage can be eternal, i.e. can continue in the next life?

Comment: Found a related question here: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/62439/are-there-any-christian-denominations-that-believe-in-sex-and-marriage-in-the-af

Comment: The question was not entirely clear, because most churches will believe in eternal marriage--that of the Lamb (see Revelation 19:7-9).  But _human_ marriage post-resurrection/translation is unbiblical (see Matthew 22:30; Mark 12:25; Luke 20:35).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Christian denominations that believe that human marriages are, or can be, eternal:

- [The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Church_of_Jesus_Christ_of_Latter-day_Saints)
- [The General Church of the New Jerusalem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Church_of_the_New_Jerusalem) (Swedenborgian)
- The General Conference of the New Church (Swedenborgian - Great Britain)
- [The Lord's New Church Which Is Nova Hierosolyma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lord%27s_New_Church_Which_Is_Nova_Hierosolyma) (Swedenborgian)
- The New Church in Australia (Swedenborgian)
- The New Church of Southern Africa (Swedenborgian)
- [The Swedenborgian Church of North America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swedenborgian_Church_of_North_America)

Comment: The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints is the largest church belonging to the [Latter-day Saint Movement](http://www.ldswm.com/Information/defining_history_large.php).  I'm not an expert on all the splinters, merges, schisms, seperations, etc., but I believe the LDS Church is the only one of the Movement that believes in eternal marriage.  (The Fundamentalists might, but they're so secretive and the media is filled with so much noise that it's hard to tell.  If true, then the "Brighamite" branch of the Moment believes in eternal marriage, but no other.)

Answer (score 0):

The Eastern Orthox Church teaches marraige is eternal and they claim that are an apostolic church oringinating back to the time of Peter. They have always taugth marriage in their chruch is eternal.

Comment: Can you support your statements with linked articles?